# How can I fix cefsharp problem after update?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I recently updated my Cefsharp.WinForms package within Nugent and it is now giving me the following error when the program tries to open a `ChromiumBrowser`.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.'
```

I have read that this is quite a common problem so tried fixing it through the C++ Redist update and through ensuring I have all .dll files needed. I have even created a new project to test it and it works. (I then copied all the .dll files from the working project over to the one that doesn't work) but I keep getting the same problem. Any idea what next steps I can take?

ps, I have also tried to solve it by reverting back to my old version.

Comment: Check your project file (.csproj) and see if the version for CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll is correct.

Comment: What version are you using? What version of. Net are you  targeting? Are you targeting x86 or x64 or AnyCpu? What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: @IlianPinzon can't see a CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll in the (.csproj) file but all other CefSharp items seem to be up to date

Comment: @amaitland CefSharp.WinForms v87.1.132 / Targeting .NET 4.6.1 / Build is set to Any CPU (I followed CefSharp instructions allowing me to do so) / I am running Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Close visual studio,  delete the bin and obj folders. Reopen then rebuild. If you are using VS2017 with packages.config then every Nuget restore/install/upgrade you'll need to close and reopen the project. There should be a message in the build log, as per https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/87/NuGet/CefSharp.Common.targets#L325 I'll probably make this a build error to make it clearer. Using the newer PackageReference Nuget implementation doesn't have this problem. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3319#issue-767059406 has details of the Nuget package restructure.

Comment: @amaitland ok great! So what I have to do is: 1. Close VS & delete the bin & obj folders 2. Reopen then rebuild 3. What are you looking me to do regarding packages?

Comment: Assuming the Nuget packages exist on disk then hopefully that should be enough to get you started. Are you using packages.config for Nuget packages?

Comment: @amaitland yes it appears that I am using packages.config.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229176/discussion-between-lhunter664-and-amaitland).

Comment: @amaitland I encountered the same problem using Visual Studio 2019. Closed it, deleted bin and obj folders and rebuilt. I am still getting the Exception from the deployed system: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found. The solution ad project platforms are x86.

Comment: Hi @UriNetanel I fixed the problem by reverting back to my old version. You can do this within the NuGet package manager.

Comment: I fixed the problem by simplifying my solution to contain all functionality within one project, like the CefSharp.MinimalExample.Winforms project. I had functionality divided between two projects previously. I deployed the program to a single folder containing both my executable and all related dlls and resources, including CefSharp  and this worked.